# asp mvc create seo friendly URL with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, seo

I am trying to create seo friendly url.

**current url:**

`http://www.example.com/Product/free-mobile-images/Mobile`

**expected ouput:**

`http://www.example.com/Product/free-mobile-images/`

I am using `id` to fetch moblie data from database.

**ActionMethod**

```
public ActionResult Product(string seotext, string id)
{

return View();

}
```

**Route.config**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Product",
                "Product/{seotext}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Product" });
```

I tried to remove moblie from the route value:

```
 RouteData.Values.Remove("id");
 RouteData.Values.Remove("Mobile");
```

But still I get /Mobile at the end of url.

May I know what wrong I am doing, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a folder structure to mimic the path you want and then call your file Index.aspx, it will have the same effect but is much simpler.

Eg folder called Product, then inside that a folder called free-mobile-images and then your file called index.aspx

Comment: hi, alex thank you for answering, but read and think before answering, i am using [asp.net mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc)  and razor and not .aspx page, your approach is not manageable always